# Change a value in a json dictionary from another json BASH

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, jq

I´ve a JSON data which is a array of dictionaries with the next syntax:

```
[ 
     {

    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 29, 2017 15:35:37",
    "Componente": "Bar",
    "Country": "Brazil",
    "Age": "3"

},

{

    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "Country": "France",
     "Id": "123456",
     "Car": "Ferrari"

}

]
```

And I've another JSON data with similar syntax EXCEPT the field of **Date_and_Time**.

```
[ 
{
  "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Age": "1",
    "Country": "France",
     "Id": "123456",
     "Car": "Ferrari"
},
{
    "Date_and_Time": "Mar 31, 2018 14:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "Country": "Germany",
     "Id": "2468",
     "Genre": "Male"

}
]
```

Both JSON data have the same number of Date_and_Time fields. What I want to do is to rewrite only the value of the first json for the value of the second json for the **Date_and_Time**

Expected output:

```
[ 
     {

    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Componente": "Bar",
    "Country": "Brazil",
    "Age": "3"

},

{

    "Date_and_Time": "Mar 31, 2018 14:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "Country": "France",
     "Id": "123456",
     "Car": "Ferrari"

}

]
```

I've thought something like send but I'd have to do each time manually the change and the perfect thing would be to automatize

Comment: Use `jq` for processing JSON in `bash`.

Comment: Those are not valid JSON values. Please fix your samples and explain the task a bit more in detail.

Comment: What do you mean by not valid?

Comment: The json is a list of dictionaries and the task is to go across every Data_Time field and the value it has to put into the another json file in the same order

Comment: It's not JSON. You have some keys and values using double quotes, some using single quotes.

Comment: You're totally right. Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm new on this

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```sh
$ jq -n --argjson oldvals "$(< file1.json)" --argjson newvals "$(< file2.json)" '
   reduce range($oldvals | length) as $idx
     ($oldvals; .[$idx].Date_and_Time = $newvals[$idx].Date_and_Time)'
[
  {
    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Componente": "Bar",
    "Country": "Brazil",
    "Age": "3"
  },
  {
    "Date_and_Time": "Mar 31, 2018 14:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "Country": "France",
    "Id": "123456",
    "Car": "Ferrari"
  }
]
```

Comment: How would you save in another file? Or how you would rewrite the results into file2.json?

Comment: @Kiko With normal shell redirection.

Comment: Could you give an example please

Comment: Any idea? I've tried the next: `> temp && mv temp Input_file`

Comment: Er... Just like any other shell redirection of a command's output to a file? A basic shell scripting tutorial might be in order if you don't know how.

Comment: @Kiko did `> temp && mv temp Input_file` not work for you in some way?

Comment: Could you add to the solution a way of saving into a file please @Shawn

Comment: `/usr/bin/jq: the list of argument is too long` @EdMorton. Besides, I've searched in some forums to fix the problem but I can´t get anything proper. I'd be really grateful for any ideas

Comment: Are you saying that that error occurs when you try to write the output to a file but doesn't occur when jq is just writing to stdout? If so, that's hard to believe. If not then don't obfuscate things by asking about writing to a file when the problem exists without writing to a file. Either way we'd need to see **exactly** the command you're executing.

Comment: `jq ... > output.json`.

Comment: @EdMorton in both cases get me that message  `/usr/bin/jq: the list of argument is too long`

Comment: Then don't obfuscate the issue by asking about failures redirecting to a file and making it sound like doing THAT is what causes the issue when redirecting to a file has absolutely nothing to do with the problem you're having since you have it while redirecting to a file or not.

Comment: You are right @edMorton, sorry for not being clear about that since the begining